# How to run method / function on instance from non-instanced class?

Tags: php, class

Pardon any mistakes in verbiage, I am trying to learn classes.

Once an object has been instantiated, I understand that methods from that class become available to me. My question is, how am I able to run methods from a class other than the instantiated one on said object?

Specifically:

```
class image {
    public static function create() {
        $image = new Imagick($file);
        $image -> image::autoRotate($image);
        ...
    }

    public static function autoRotate($image) {
        ...
    }
}
```

the line $image -> image::autoRotate($image) yields the error, and I understand the syntax and/or my understanding are at fault. Can someone kindly help me understand how to accomplish this please?

Comment: you don't need `$image->` part

Comment: also class name should be camelcased by convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the the `image` class isn't actually a property of the `$image` object, you don't need to use the `$image ->` syntax to perform that operation. Since `autoRotate()` is a *static* function, it can be called just from the class accessor `image::autoRotate($image);`

```
class image {
    public static function create() {
        $image = new Imagick($file);
        image::autoRotate($image); // removed $image ->
    ...
    }

    public static function autoRotate($image) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

public static function can be called directly by `classname::funcname`, no need to instantiate an object first. In your case:

```
class image {
    public static function create() {
        $image = new Imagick($file);
        image::autoRotate($image);
        ...
    }

    public static function autoRotate($image) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace line ..

```
$image -> image::autoRotate($image);
```

with this one..

```
self::autoRotateImage($image);
```